# Configure /etc/fstab for external hard drive

Tags: mount, kde, automounting, external-hdd, kde5

In my `/etc/fstab` I have the line

```
UUID=c99...04c4  /media/myExtDrive  ext4    defaults,user,nobootwait  0   0
```

for my external hard drive. But when I plug it in and try to mount it with the DeviceNotifier of my KDE Plasma 5, I get the message that the device cannot be mounted. This was no problem in my Kubuntu 14.04 with KDE 4. When I delete the above line in `/etc/fstab`, the DeviceNotifier is able to mount the hard drive - however to `/media/user/myExtDriveName` instead to `/media/myExtDrive` as I wish. How do I need to configure the line in `/etc/fstab` so that it will be mounted automatically if present, but still allows me to use the DeviceNotifier to mount to `/media/myExtDrive`?

---

EDIT 1: I just tried to mount the external hdd with `sudo mount --all` with the line in `fstab`, but that did not allow me to mount either. Not quite sure why.

---

EDIT 2: In Kubuntu 14.04, the folder `/media/myExtDrive` had to be created. Now, I also created `/media/myExtDrive`. If I don't I get the error message, did get the message that it is missing. But somehow I am not quite sure anymore in which situation and have trouble reproducing this.

---

EDIT 3: When trying to mount with `sudo mount -va` I get

> Incorrect filesystem type, invalid options, `/dev/sdd1` superblock is damaged, encoding page missing or some other error.

However, I do not have any issues mounting to `/media/user/myExtDriveName` if I remove the above line in `/etc/fstab` and mount via DeviceNotifier.

Whether I have the folder `/media/myExtDrive` created beforehand or not seems not to make any difference either way.

The command `tail -f /var/log/messages` just returns that the file `/var/log/messages` cannot be found and thus can't be opened.

Comment: Does `/media/myExtDrive` exist? Edit your question and include the errors you're getting.

Comment: I'm not a KDE user, so all of this is probably wrong, but here are some thoughts... Regarding `sudo mount --all`, check `dmesg` for errors and `mount` output, it might already be mounted... it's possible that disconnecting the device physically doesn't automatically remove the mtab entry... Have you tried a reboot?

Comment: @Panki: I updated the question. Did that help?

Comment: @rfmodulator: I am pretty sure it is not mounted and I did reboot.

Comment: Run `'tail -f /var/log/messages` while mounting the drive and `mount -va` and add the output of both to your question.

Comment: @NasirRiley: Did that help?

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with Plasma and `fstab` too. I couldn't mount it automatically, so I created an script to run in startup.

There are multiple ways of achieving it, I'd suggest to create a system service, to make the script to run as root when the computer starts:

**First:** Go to the `systemd` scripts folder:

```
$ cd /etc/systemd/system
```

**Second:** Create a script file

```
$ sudo touch Automount.sh
```

**Third:** List the storage devices you have connected and identify your desired disk to mount.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

The output will be generated as follows (just illustrative example):

```
#######################---------Example output-----------#####################

Disk /dev/sda: 931,51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     34      32767      32734    16M mydisktoo
/dev/sda2  32768 1953521663 1953488896 931,5G mydisk

#######################---------Example output-----------#####################
```

**Fourth:** Edit the script to mount the file

```
$ sudo nano Automount.service
```

Write this inside the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Here you detail what you want to detail about the created service

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/Automount.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[image: Example of the interface of the nano text editor.]

And save it pressing [Ctrl] + [X], and then [Y]

**Fifth:** Edit the mounting script

```
$ sudo nano Automount.sh
```

and paste your favorite mount configuration.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount /dev/YOURDRIVEIDENTIFIER /media/MYEXTERNALDRIVE
```

**Fifth:** Make the script executable for all users

```
$ sudo chmod +x Automount.sh
```

**Sixth** Test your script by starting your new service

```
$ systemctl start Automount.service
```

**Finally:** Enable autorun at system startup

```
$ systemctl enable Automount.service
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sounds good. What do I do when I plug the external hard drive in during work (so, after system startup) and how do I unmount?

Comment: It is a wonderful question. Let me think, maybe using `awk` to get the `/dev/XXX` identifier and making the script more sophisticated... But in my computer I used to mount the devices with problems like this one manually using `sudo mount /dev/XXX /My/FAV/PATH`

Comment: Then you can simply unmount it using `sudo umount /dev/XXX`, first making sure no process is using it.

Comment: How is this different to using fstab? It seems like it is pretty much the same in the sense as both use `mount`. Is it "only" that yours works? Possibly because your script runs much later in the booting process? Did I get this right?